# USB to TTL "for arduino" compatible with Pi?

Tags: arduino

Not real familiar with these devices yet; is there any difference between this, where it says "for arduino" and perhaps one for a raspberry pi? I have a Pi and just want to confirm whether I need to find one **specific** for Pi?

[image]

I messaged the seller this question and this is the response I got (lol):

> I apologize, we are unable to check this.

My assumption is they're usable on both since it's just "colored wires", but want to make sure before I wait 7 years to get one of these sent from China. ;)

Update: Including a link to the device page, in case it provides more useful specs - https://x.geekdrop.com/3BfNVfQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look into the [datasheet](http://www.prolific.com.tw/UserFiles/files/ds_pl2303HXD_v1_4_4.pdf) of the converter chip (PL2303HX), you will see it's a 3.3V device with 5V tolerant inputs. It is therefore suitable for both Arduino and the Pi.

Answer (score 0):

If the vendor doesn't know how to works and can't supply a data sheet we can't know either.

Pi peripherals NEED to work @ 3.3V and isn't TTL (but then most of these devices aren't TTL either).

Comment: I thought that a bit strange myself; the seller has over 16K feedback but can't tell me about his own product. Maybe hoping I'll just take the gamble and buy it anyway.

Comment: Also, not sure what ya mean by Pi periphs need to NOT be TTL? Or am I reading that wrong? I'm wanting to follow this guide: https://ipcamtalk.com/threads/dahua-ipc-unbricking-recovery-over-serial-uart-and-tftp.16474/ and it says not to use RS232 because it's 12v?

Comment: I just updated the OP with a link to the device, in case it provides any useful tech info.

Comment: @J.ScottElblein TTL is a 5V current driven interface. The Pi and most devices, almost certainly including the adapter are CMOS - voltage driven; actual levels vary, but are a percentage of supply voltage. I didn't bother to point out that the adapter isn't RS232 which is strictly ±15V bipolar with inverted levels.